# Как получить свое местоположение и поставить маркер на google карте в android приложении?

Tags: android, google-maps

Здравствуйте! Как получить свое местоположение на карте? Есть google map activity пустое ничего своего не писал. И надо сразу  при запуске этого активити поставить маркер на местоположении пользователя. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Что конкретно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

1) Вам понадобится [API ключ от гугла.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/306-urok-139-google-maps-sozdanie-i-nastrojka-proekta-karta-kamera-sobytija.html)

2) [Пример работы с картой гугл.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/307-urok-140-google-maps-svoi-obekty-na-karte.html)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).